# Saving an accde file from MS Access 2013 to MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am getting an error message from work computer which has MS Access 2010 telling me that the accde file which i saved on my machine at home (MS Access 2013) is uncompatible due to the different version of Access. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, there is not. Use the accdb, not accde.

Comment: That is a shame. At the moment I a very concerned with security and protection of intellectual capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access 2010 cannot open an .accde file created by Access 2013. However, Access 2013 *can* open an .accde created by Access 2010.

If you want an .accde that can be opened by both Access 2010 and Access 2013 then create the .accde in Access 2010.

Also be aware that an .accde created by a 64-bit version of Access cannot be opened by a 32-bit version, and vice versa.